# Count task in application

Tags: java

I am currently taking an introduction to Java class.  I am a few weeks ahead of the class so this assignment is not due for a couple weeks. I have found topics on this issue before but it did not seem to work for me.

The task is:

> **The application should also display a table of potential total annual compensation that the salesperson could have earned, in $5000 increments above the salesperson’s annual sales, until it reaches 50% above the salesperson’s annual sales.**

The portion of the code that is not working as intended:

```
    for (double count = annualSales; count <= ((annualSales * .03) + 
            annualSales); count+=5000)
        {
    System.out.println(count + "\t\t" + total);
        }
```

The output for this code is:

> 80000.0  0.0

I received this snippet of code from this site and it works.  However, I wanted the output to generate ten outputs starting from the annualSales.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see the help center How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially: **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

Comment: This for loop is comprised of an initialization (double count = annualSales) an if statement (count <= ((annualSales * .03) + annualSales) ) and an increment function (count += 5000).  If you want to loop 10 times, change the if statement to for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) and move the other logic into the for loop itself.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Unfortunately, I do not understand what you are explaining to do.  I am very new to Java (First week) and your answer confused me (This is definitely my fault).  Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: You shouldn't really be doing calculations in a constructor, they're only for initializing the class. Your nested class and constructor should really just be a single method of the `DykhoffWk2Calculator` class. I realize that the requirements indicate you need a second class, so why not just use a class for your main and then a Calculator class for all your calculation methods?

Comment: @JGrice are you saying the the counter should be in it's own nested class and then call it to the main class?  I already have one class that uses calculation (Nestcalc).  Should I treat this the same way as Nestcalc?

Comment: @TravisDykhoff I'm saying that you need reconsider how you designed your code. This is unrelated your issue with the count and is more of a structuring issue. I'm suggesting you have 2 classes: 1 that includes your main; a second that is your calculator class (Neither of the classes needs to be nested) You then have `Nestedcalc()` constructor not be a constructor but instead a method of your calculator class.

Comment: @durron597 I edited the question to conform to site guidelines. I hate being the new guy and getting negative votes.  Thank you very much for you guidance.

Comment: @JGrice Thank you very much.  I will delve into this more.

Comment: @TravisDykhoff Upvoted + retracted close vote. Thank you for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this snippet:

```
 for (double count = annualSales; count <= ((annualSales * .03) + 
        annualSales); count+=5000)
    {
    System.out.println(count + "\t\t" + total);
    }
```

and instead you want to execute this 10 times, this means you want your for loop to look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   //do something here
}
```

Now, it looks like you are wanting to calculate 1.03 * annual sales + 5000 based on your old for loop, to do this 10 times you would want to do:

```
count = 1.03 * annualsales + 5000;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   count = 1.03 * count + 5000;
   System.out.println("Your total is: " + count);
}
```

Whatever your inner logic is that executes 10 times goes inside the loop (including print statements if you want to see the values as you go.  The original for loop you had is good if you want to restrict the number of executions based on the value of count vs the value of annualSales.  This middle condition on a for loop is just a conditional statement, so it can be anything (even 1==1 which means the loop will run forever).

Comment: The code that you provided created 10 instances which is perfect.  However, it is just repeating the totalCompensation for some reason.  I need it to increase by 5000 on each instance starting at the totalCompensation.  Here is the output that it gave me.

Comment: Here is the run:

> run:

What was the total of your annual sales this year?:

150000

Your annual salary was: $45000.0

Your total commission was: $5625.0

Your total compensation was: $50625.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

Your total is: 192500.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)"

Comment: see modified answer.  now it builds on itself.

Comment: Now I am getting a bug stating: variable count is already defined in method main(String[]).

Comment: remove the double in front of count.  Sounds like its declared earlier in your method and you only declare a variable once.

Comment: I just defined count as static in the beginning and it worked.  However, the instances are not increasing by 5000 every time.

"Your total is: 10625.0
Your total is: 10625.0
Your total is: 10625.0
Your total is: 10625.0"